# Trying to create a toggle effect hide text/show different text while chaning my arrow up/arrow down using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to toggle my summary text hidden/ showing my main text while changing the status of my up and down arrow using $(this) to target specific clicks.

At the moment it's opening all the divs rather than targeting the one clicked. Also the up/down arrow isn't working properly, only fires every second time

This is the link: http://codepen.io/1eddy87/pen/lsyIw

Also, if someone could help me put in more/less when the arrow toggle/clicked it would just be just GREAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the `<i>` tags onClick to trigger `showBody`, and inside of THAT you added the click function on `<i>`. Then you use a selector `$('.first > .sum')` which will pick up ALL elements matching that, which in your case is two of them, and hide or show all of them accordingly.

It would be easier to remove the `showBody` function, and move the `<i>` onclick inside the div. Then you can use `$(this)` to show/hide the other bits of the div:

```
$('i').click(function() {
  var tog = $(this);
  tog.parent().find('.main').toggleClass('hide');
  tog.toggleClass('fa fa-chevron-up fa fa-chevron-down');
  return false;
});
```

[new codepen](http://codepen.io/jorgt/pen/GyoEL)

Wasn't sure if you want to hide the summary on click as well, but that's just adding another toggleClass line for the summary.

Comment: Dude, plain and simple. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Also consider using a class for the click function instead of straight up `<i>` so you're not applying that click to all icons on your page

Comment: I have recreated exactly what I need and I'm having a issue implementing the code can you please help me out. I need it in this specific format - link http://codepen.io/1eddy87/pen/purLi

Comment: Looks ok to me... What exactly in there is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you'll want to put your jquery link before your bootstrap, to avoid later headaches. Bootstrap's javascript requires the jquery library.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, will do. Should it be at the bottom of the page or the top??